# Modify field value before this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit();

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have an LWC component in which I'm using lightning-record-edit-form. I have a custom submit button. That is outside lightning record edit form. I don't have the 'Name' field in the HTML; instead, I want to update its value before submitting the form, but I'm always getting an undefined value.
JS:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log('>>> Inside Handle submit... '+this.selectedValue);
        event.preventDefault();

        const recordEditForm = this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form');
        console.log('>>> recordEditForm... '+JSON.stringify(recordEditForm));

        if (recordEditForm) {
            console.log('>>> Inside if... ');
            const fields = recordEditForm.fields; // Get the current fields
            console.log('>>> fields... '+fields);
            // Modify the field value (assuming 'FieldName' is the API name of the field)
            fields.Name.value = 'Test Name';

            // Trigger form submission with the updated fields
            recordEditForm.submit(fields);
        }
}
```

My ***recordEditForm.fields*** is always undefined. I'm not sure how to modify value of field if that is not added in layout before submit.

Answer (score 1):

When overriding the onsubmit behavior, access to the fields object is available through `event.details.fields`. From there, you can add Name to the object and set whatever value you choose. This allows you to keep the standard commit button but intercept the submit action.

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import DESCRIPTION_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Description";
import WEBSITE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Website";

export default class AcctEdit extends LightningElement {
  // Expose a field to make it available in the template
  descriptionField = DESCRIPTION_FIELD;
  websiteField = WEBSITE_FIELD;

  // Flexipage provides recordId and objectApiName
  @api recordId;
  @api objectApiName;

  otherSaveHandler(event) {
    console.log("other save handler clicked");
    this.refs.hiddenButton.click();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formFields = event.detail.fields;

    if (formFields) {
      console.log(">>> Inside if... ");
      console.log(formFields);
      formFields.Name = "Test Name";

      // Trigger form submission with the updated fields
      this.template
        .querySelector("lightning-record-edit-form")
        .submit(formFields);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <lightning-record-edit-form
    object-api-name={objectApiName}
    record-id={recordId}
    onsubmit={handleSubmit}
  >
    <lightning-input-field field-name={descriptionField}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name={websiteField}></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-button lwc:ref="hiddenButton" variant="brand" type="submit" label="hidden save" hidden></lightning-button>
  </lightning-record-edit-form>
  <lightning-button variant="brand" onclick={otherSaveHandler} label="Save">
  </lightning-button>
</template>
```

Comment: My lightning button is outside lightning record edit form

Comment: In that case, you'll need an additional onclick handler (see revisions above). The original submit button must stay in place but can be hidden via a HTML attribute.